# Add a return at the end of the FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Future here but says that needs to add a return but I don't know how that works hehe

> ```
> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type.
> Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
> ```

That's the error that show's up when I wrote this code

> ```
>   body: Center(
>     child: FutureBuilder(
>       future: getAllData(),
>       builder: (context, snapshot) {
>         if (snapshot.hasData) {
>           if (data.contains('empty')) {
>             return const Text('No data');
>           } else {
>             ListView.builder(
>                 itemCount: data.length,
>                 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
>                   return ListTile(
>                     title: Text("${data[index]["subject"]}"),
>                     trailing: Text("${data[index]["endtime"]}"),
>                   );
>                 });
>           }
>         } else {
>           return const CircularProgressIndicator();
>         }
>       },
>     ),
>   ),
> ```

Anybody can help? Thanks anyway

Comment: I guess in the first else, you want to return the Listview.builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is expected to return a Widget in all cases. In the case of your ListView.builder however you are returning nothing. Change the code to

```
return ListView.builder(...)
```